# Why when i overriding base.html django-admin has been disable responsive interface?

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-templates, django-admin

It seems like all ok for desktop interface but doesn't work correctly for mobile devices. This trouble is appear only when i put my custom `base.html`.

Answer (score 0):

try clearing you browser cache by **CONT + Shift + R**
it is some time your browser cache problem that your admin interface didn't load correctly.

Comment: I has been seen this on many devices and getting same result.